# Creating different EC2 instances in separate AZs using for each terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, private, nat, private-subnet

I am trying to deploy different EC2 instances in separate AZs using terraform. I am then associating the subnets the EC2 instances are on to a route table with a NAT gateway. I am getting stuck on associating the subnets with the nat gateway on the route table. Below is my code and error. Any advice would be helpful.

```
resource "aws_instance" "private" {
  for_each      = var.priv_subnet
  ami           = var.ec2_amis[var.region]
  instance_type = each.key
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.main.key_name
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.private[each.key].id

  tags = {
    Name = each.value.tag
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "nat" {
  for_each = var.pub_subnet
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.main[each.key].id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_tags}_${each.key}_PrivRT"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "nat" {
  for_each       = aws_subnet.private
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.nat[each.key].id
  subnet_id      = each.value.id
}
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each                = var.priv_subnet
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.tableau.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, each.value.subnet)
  availability_zone       = each.value.availability_zone
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags = {
    Name = "PrivSub-${each.value.availability_zone}"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "main" {
  for_each = aws_subnet.public
  vpc      = true

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "tableau" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.public
  subnet_id     = each.value.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.main[each.key].id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each                = var.pub_subnet
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, each.value)
  availability_zone       = each.key
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "PubSub-${each.key}"
  }
}
```

**Variables**

```
variable "priv_subnet" {


 type = map(object({
    availability_zone = string
    subnet            = string
    tag               = string
  }))
  default = {
    "m5.2xlarge" = {
      availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
      subnet            = 4
      tag               = "Primary"
    }
    "m5.4xlarge" = {
      availability_zone = "us-west-2b"
      subnet            = 5
      tag               = "Worker1"
    }
    "m5.4xlarge" = {
      availability_zone = "us-west-2c"
      subnet            = 6
      tag               = "Worker2"
    }
  }
}

variable "pub_subnet" {
  default = {
    "us-west-2a" = 1
    "us-west-2b" = 2
    "us-west-2c" = 3
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Error: Invalid index

  on vpc.tf line 99, in resource "aws_route_table_association" "nat":
  99:   route_table_id = aws_route_table.nat[each.key].id
    |----------------
    | aws_route_table.nat is object with 3 attributes
    | each.key is "m5.2xlarge"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.


Error: Invalid index

  on vpc.tf line 99, in resource "aws_route_table_association" "nat":
  99:   route_table_id = aws_route_table.nat[each.key].id
    |----------------
    | aws_route_table.nat is object with 3 attributes
    | each.key is "m5.4xlarge"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

I understand the error message but am unsure how to appropriately assign the routes to this route table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `each.key` in the `aws_route_table_association` will be instance types from  `priv_subnet`, e.g. `m5.2xlarge`. However, `aws_route_table.nat` keys will be AZ names, such as `us-east-1a`, from `var.pub_subnet`.

Obviously, this does not work. One way to overcome the issue would be to **modify** your `priv_subnet` variable to use subnet names as keys, not instance types. The change would probably require further changes to your code.

```
variable "priv_subnet" {

 type = map(object({
    instance_type     = string
    subnet            = string
    tag               = string
  }))

  default = {
    "us-west-2a" = {
      instance_type = "m5.2xlarge"
      subnet            = 4
      tag               = "Primary"
    }
    "us-west-2b" = {
      instance_type     = "m5.4xlarge"
      subnet            = 5
      tag               = "Worker1"
    }
    "us-west-2c" = {
      instance_type     = "m5.4xlarge"
      subnet            = 6
      tag               = "Worker2"
    }
  }
}
```

This way you would have **one-to-one** relationship between `var.pub_subnet` and `var.priv_subnet`, which would simplify things in my view.

Comment: Thank you. Your advice helped me figure it out. I did have to change some parts of my each objects!

Comment: @DaveMichaels No problem. Glad it worked out. I imagined other changes would be required, but I think in the long term, it will be better.